# Calling "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" across an APN

Tags: android, google-maps, apn

In Android I'm using the following snippet to load Google maps:

```
Uri geoURI = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + source +  &daddr=" + destination);
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoURI);
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Over Wifi or a 3G network, the functionality works fine, but over our APN it fails.  Does the link redirect to some other address or go to some domain that I also need to register with our APN?

Comment: Try to change your APN to see how it works: http://www.androidcentral.com/what-apn-and-how-do-i-change-it

Comment: When testing through the Google Maps app directly, it appears to get stuck on the message 'Getting driving directions'

Comment: It appears that the APN was blacklisting the maps.google.com IP equivalent as it mapped to the same IP as YouTube at the time and this was blocked